# Torch implementation of multi-output-layer neural network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution, torch

I am going to build a neural network which has an architecture of more than one output layers. More specificly, it is designed to construct parallel procedures on top of a series of convolutional layers. One branch is to compute classification results (softmax-like); the other is to get regression results. However, I'm stuck designing the model as well as choosing loss functions(criterions).

I. Should I use torch container `nn.Parallel()` or `nn.Concat()` for the branch layers on top of conv layers (`nn.Sequential()`)? What is the differenct except for data format.

II. Due to output data, a classification loss function and a regression loss function are to be combined linearly. I am wondering whether `nn.MultiCriterion()` or `nn.ParallelCriterion()` to be chosen with respect to determined container. Or I have to customize a new criterion class.

III. Could anyone who had done similar work tell me if torch needs additional customization to implement backprop for training. I concern about data structure issue of torch containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Concat` vs `Parallel` differ in that each module in `Concat` gets the entire output of the last layer as input, while each input of `Parallel` takes a slice of the output of the last layer. For your purpose you need `Concat`, not `Parallel`, since both loss functions need to take the entire output of your sequential network.
2. Based on the source code of `MultiCriterion` and `ParallenCriterion` they do practically the same thing. The important difference is that in case of `MultiCriterion` you provide multiple loss functions, but only one target, and they are all computed against that target. Given that you have a classification and a regression task I assume you have different targets, so you need `ParallelCriterion(false)`, where `false` enables the multitarget mode (if the argument is `true` `ParallelCriterion` seems to behave identical to `MultiCriterion`). Then the `target` is expected to be a table of targets for individual criterions.
3. If you use `Concat` and `ParallelCriterion`, torch should be able to compute gradients properly for you. The both implement `updateGradInput`, which properly merges the gradients of individual blocks.